# jQuery validation for date and time field in a bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a bootsrap form with some jQuery validation, which is not working properly at the moment and I don't have sufficient knowledge to make it work. 
What I am aiming to do is when the submit button is clicked the validation should show a message if the fields isn't set according to my validation standards.
The problem is that I have a fields for date and time and I dont know how to make the validation work for them. They have a some default values and basically now I can save the default values instead of some valid date and time.

Currently, I am only able to see the message for the `reason` field in the form when it's not set according to the validation standard.

Here is the form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal form" id="validate-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2 " class="dpckr" >
        <!-- <input class="form-control " id="date " name="date " placeholder="MM/DD/YYY " type="text "/> -->
          <input id="date" type="text " class="form-control datepicker" name="date" value="Click to select date" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="text ">Hour:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2 ">
          <select class="form-control sct" id="time" name="time">
            <option value="" class=" ">Time</option>
            <option value="10am " class=" ">10:00-10:30</option>
            <option value="1030am " class=" ">10:30-11:00</option>
           </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 " for="reason ">Reason:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <textarea class="form-control " id="reason" name="reason" placeholder="Describe the reason" rows="5 "></textarea><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 ">
          <button id="saveAppt" type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And the form validation :

```
 $("#validate-form").validate({
    //specify the validation rules
    rules: {
    date: "required",
    time: "required",
    reason: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 40
    }
    },

    messages: {
    date: "Date must be selected!",
    sct: {
    required: "Time option must be selected!",
    },
    reason: {
    required: "Reason filed cannot be blank!",
    minlength: "Reason must be descibed in at least 40 characters."
    }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form){
    form.submit();
    }

    });
```

It is also not clear to me how I can trigger this validation when the `submit` button is clicked?

Should I put it in the  `$("#saveAppt").click(function(e)`, which is binded to the submit button of the form shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the validation plugin should automatically capture the submit event as long as you're actually submitting the form, try changing the type of your button from "button" to "submit" or just remove it all together (the majority of browsers will fall back to submit if no type is provided).

```
      <button id="saveAppt" type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Submit</button>
```

EDIT:

I've set up a jsfiddle for you where you can see the code working although it needs some styling. Check your console to ensure there's no errors stopping your validation plugin from running.

https://jsfiddle.net/vc4vvrL0/7/

Comment: i tried, but the on click the form is  still submitted and the validation still doesn't work for my date and time fields

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? Also change value="Click to select date" to placeholder="Click to select date" as it'll cause the validation plugin to assume it's been filled in.